# devise_token_auth api authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication

I am using devise_token_auth's 
'`config.change_headers_on_each_request = true`' to reset auth headers on each api request.
But, the access-token is not being returned in response headers.

devise_token_auth.rb:

```
DeviseTokenAuth.setup do |config|
  config.change_headers_on_each_request = true
end
```

Application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Sign in API response headers include:

```
access-token: xxxxx
token-type: xxxx
client: xxxxx
expiry: xxxxx
uid: xxxxx
```

I passed all these parameters in request headers in other APIs, but response doesn't include all these parameters.

Using:

```
gem 'devise_token_auth', git: 'https://github.com/jasonswett/devise_token_auth.git'
```

Comment: I would recommend using https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth instead